# cosign image signature verification from kubernetes not working

Tags: image, signature, verification, cosign-api

I use this link for image signature verification with cosign. 'cosign verify' working  before pull by kubernetes. I install sigstore and create secret as below but kubernetes not create pod with signed image. I use this link but not working: https://sysdig.com/blog/secure-kubernetes-deployment-signature-verification/. Please support me:

```
cosign verify --key cosign.pub   muradsamadov/contenttrust:signed | jq .

Verification for index.docker.io/muradsamadov/contenttrust:signed --
The following checks were performed on each of these signatures:
  - The cosign claims were validated
  - Existence of the claims in the transparency log was verified offline
  - The signatures were verified against the specified public key
[
  {
    "critical": {
      "identity": {
        "docker-reference": "index.docker.io/muradsamadov/contenttrust"
      },
      "image": {
        "docker-manifest-digest": "sha256:30e6d35703c578ee703230b9dc87ada2ba958c1928615ac8a674fcbbcbb0f281"
      },
      "type": "cosign container image signature"
    },
    "optional": {
      "Bundle": {
        "SignedEntryTimestamp": "MEUCIDiG6KvLgJfjQfDucJGmgoxOWU62YeMX2sPIOtm0LQ/5AiEA2R/NfnsbbTU4ofUg1B8XFQnJx+MAkzarv/Q8hAerk0c=",
        "Payload": {
          "body": "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",
          "integratedTime": 1686939096,
          "logIndex": 24000966,
          "logID": "c0d23d6ad406973f9559f3ba2d1ca01f84147d8ffc5b8445c224f98b9591801d"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

```
k run test --image muradsamadov/contenttrust:signed -n testcontenttrust
Error from server (BadRequest): admission webhook "cosigned.sigstore.dev" denied the request: validation failed: no matching signatures:
unable to verify bundle: retrieving rekor public key: updating local metadata and targets: error updating to TUF remote mirror: tuf: invalid key
remote status:{
    "mirror": "sigstore-tuf-root",
    "metadata": {
        "root.json": {
            "version": 7,
            "len": 5404,
            "expiration": "04 Oct 23 13:08 UTC",
            "error": ""
        },
        "snapshot.json": {
            "version": 90,
            "len": 2303,
            "expiration": "03 Jul 23 16:03 UTC",
            "error": ""
        },
        "targets.json": {
            "version": 7,
            "len": 5252,
            "expiration": "04 Oct 23 13:26 UTC",
            "error": ""
        },
        "timestamp.json": {
            "version": 90,
            "len": 721,
            "expiration": "26 Jun 23 16:03 UTC",
            "error": ""
        }
    }
}: spec.containers[0].image
index.docker.io/muradsamadov/contenttrust@sha256:30e6d35703c578ee703230b9dc87ada2ba958c1928615ac8a674fcbbcbb0f281
```